# Module that can both detect Voltage (12V) and Control current

Tags: relay, voltage

I need a module for ARDUINO that can both detect Voltage (12V) **and** Control current between 2 pins (12V), like a relay on another device

I have found relay modules to control pins and another module for 4-channel Voltage detection, but it seems like a lot of components and wiring.

Is there any module that can do both?

Comment: are you detecting "control current" or are you controlling current? ... how much current are you talking about?

Comment: DC or AC current?

Comment: Just opening/closing the connection between two pins. My bad for poor expl.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need another module to detect voltage on an Arduino.  The UNO, which I assume you are using, has 6 analog inputs (A0-A5) that can directly read voltage.  The only problem is that you want to measure a voltage up to 12V and the Arduino can only handle 5V.  So the solution is to DIVIDE that using two resistors in a voltage-divider configuration so that you only see 5V at the Arduino when there is 12V on the signal.

From here: https://www.electroniclinic.com/what-is-a-voltage-divider-or-potential-divider-formula-and-practical-uses/

you can see how to make one:

[image]

As far as controlling a "current" that is usually done with a relay.  There are no on-board relays but there are the digital outputs that can drive a small relay or can be connected via some other circuitry like a couple of transistors to drive just about any size relay.

Comment: I just want to detect hi/lo. Sorry for poor expl. And also connect/disconnect between two (other) pins, lile a relay

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest opto-isolators for both directions.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs8B2Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For the Ardiuno sending control signal you have to know which way round to connect to the inputs of your controller. Chances are one will be ground - that's "CTL Low".

Comment: Would this component do the same https://www.adafruit.com/product/1875 ?

Comment: No. If you read that page you will see it says 3.3v to 5v not 5v to 12v.

Comment: I meant as a priciple, not the exact numbers :o). Im looking for a component and as little how brewed as possible. It will be used on a lock, so I prefer components